# Order a dataframe with columname indexed as colnumber

Tags: r

I can easily order a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,5,7,2),b=(1:5))
# indexing by column name, works
df2<-df[with(df,order(a)),]
```

But how can I achive the same by indexing with the column number?

```
# indexing with column number, attemps failed
df2<-df[with(df,order(colnames(df[1]))),]
df2<-df[with(df,order(deparse(colnames(df[1])))),]
df2<-df[with(df,order(paste(colnames(df[1])))),]
df2<-df[with(df,order(paste(deparse(colnames(df[1]))))),]
```

Comment: I think you mean "But how can I achive the same by indexing with the column **number**?"

Comment: yes. i cleared that out. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
df2 <- df[order(df[,1]),]
```

If you use `with` you won't be able to use column numbers.